# GA4 - showing specific rows in a line chart

Tags: google-analytics-4

I have an issue with GA4. I want to display specific row from a table under the charts in Line chart. It is displaying just Organic Search, Paid Search, Cross network, Direct, Email. What shall I do if I want to dislplay for example "Paid Social" data in a line chart.
Could somebody navigate me?
[image]